# Applied force keeps the node moving

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a top-down game of pool. The entire view is the table, and then I have number of ball-nodes. When I apply force to the balls, they keep moving for quite long time, where I'd like the force to wear off faster. Since I haven't been working too much with physics before I am having a difficult time figuring out which propert(y/ies) to adjust.

I have a quite high `restitution` (0.8) on the balls, because I want them to bounce off the edges. The edges are defined by this node:

```
SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: CGRect(x: -self.size.width/2.0, y: -self.size.height/2.0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
```

I see that there is a `friction` property on the `SKShapeNode` class. I am feeling that it might be the right one to use, but it doesn't seem to help when I turn it up.

So what is the right approach - how do I make the applied force wear off faster?

Comment: Try adjusting the physics body's `linearDamping` property. The value must be between 0 and 1.0, where 0 results in no damping and 1 provides maximum damping (slows faster).

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. If you create an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: Try to think of linearDamping like air resistance or water resistance, and friction as your ground resistance (This will allow you to have different felt types while maintaining a similar feel in physics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting the physics body's `linearDamping` property will allow you to change the rate at which the body slows over time ([linearDamping doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519796-lineardamping)). The value should be between 0 and 1.0, where 0 results in no damping and 1 provides maximum damping (slows faster).